# How to select multiple checkboxes in selenium(java)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select all checkboxes whose value is matched to my value.
Code is working fine when the web page has no vertical scroll. But if web page has some more data then the checkbox is not selected as I want.

Here is my code-

```
List<WebElement> rselect = tagdis1.findElements(By.className("row-selection-checkbox"));
System.out.println("Row selection Size- " + rselect.size());
List<WebElement> record = driver.findElements(By.id("$ctrl.item.id"));
System.out.println("Size- " + record.size());
int DocNameCount = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < record.size(); j++) {

    String Pname = record.get(j).getText();
    System.out.println("Pdf name- " + Pname);

    if (Pname.equals(docName + ".pdf")) {
       // here total 4 records i get but able to click only on 3 records
        System.out.println(j + " " + Pname);
        rselect.get(j).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to share URL?

Comment: Then you need login credentials

Comment: Please share the HTML of page

Comment: Did you get html ?

Comment: I can see this only `Html - ActionRecorded timeNameMatterCategoryLast edit atReceived atCommentsContactUploaded byUploaded dateID`

Comment: its too much lenthier

Comment: can i get your personal details for further discussion?

Comment: Why not simply move to element before click it? https://www.scientecheasy.com/2020/01/move-element-in-selenium.html/

Comment: okay let me try

Answer (score 0):

Please use scroll option in your operation,

```
/*
 * By
 * scroll to the element and wait
 */
public void scroll(By element){
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",driver.findElement(element));
    log.info("Scrolling down");
}
```